# Is the state space of a transient irreductible Markov chain infinite?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

We know that if we have a Markov chain $(X_n)$ on an finite state space $S$ and with at least one recurrent state then the chain is irreducible and hence recurrent.

**So my question is : If we have an irreducible Markov chain $(X_n)$ with one transient state then does that mean that the state space $S$ is infinite?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Recall that an irreducible chain is one where the entire state space $S$ is a single communicating class. In this case clearly $S$ is closed.

Further, recurrence/transience is a class property. So in an irreducible chain, either every state is recurrent or every state is transient.

It is a theorem that for a closed class $C$, then $C$ finite $\implies$ $C$ is recurrent (this is very closely related to the fact that you state).

So for an irreducible chain, applying the contrapositive of this theorem to the closed class $S$ gives: $S$ transient $\implies$ $S$ is infinite.

Comment: The question was: if one has an irreducible Markov chain with ONE transient state then does that mean that the state space S is infinite? In my opinion, "an irreducible Markov chain with ONE transient state" can never exist. Thus it is not clear for me, how your answer addresses the original question.

Comment: @rrv it is a theorem that in an irreducible chain, existence of a transient state $\implies$ every state is transient. My interpretation is that "irreducible Markov chain with one transient state" means "an irreducible Markov chain in which there exists a transient state (possibly more than one)".

Comment: So, according to me, you've given the (absolutely correct) answer but to the different question. The original question remains unanswered.