# Recurrence of random walk in a finite set

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let $(S_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a random walk in $\Bbb Z^d$ starting at $x$. Let $$N=\sum_{n \geq 0}\Bbb 1_{S_k=x} $$
be the random variable representing the number of visits of $(S_n)$ to
its starting point $x$.

I know that if $d \geq 3$, then $(S_n)$ is transient i.e. $\Bbb P(N < \infty)=1$. But what if the random walk $(S_n)$ is constrained to a finite set $G \subset \Bbb Z^d$ ? To me, $(S_n)$ will have "much less space" to move, infinitely less space than in $\Bbb Z^2$ where all walks are recurrent so $\Bbb P(N = \infty)=1$ when $S_n$ is a finite subset of $\Bbb Z^d$. However I cannot find a formal proof of this fact. Does someone have one or a link/document I can read ?

Comment: If the walk is "constrained to a finite set" then the terminology of Markov chains might apply.  One requires that the probability of transition from state $i$ to state $j$ is time invariant.  If this applies to your case, I can point out some references.

Comment: yes feel free @hardmath

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Knowing that our "random walk" involves only a finite number of states does not by itself imply that "all walks are recurrent."  If the transition probabilities between states depend only on the states (and not upon what time a step is taken), then the random walk can be modelled as a finite Markov process.  That is, we can write the [row stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) of transition probabilities from state $i$ to state $j$ with entries $p_{ij}$ as $M$.  Multiplying a row vector $v= (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ representing an initial state $x$ by $1$ in the $x$ position (otherwise zero) by a positive integer power $n$ of $M$:

$$ v M^n $$

gives us a row vector with the probability distribution of states after the $n$th step.

These definitions are [conventional for Markov chains](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.110/lehre/ws13/Stochastik_II/Skript_2B.pdf): a state is *recurrent* if starting from that means it will recur infinitely often with probability $1$, a state is *transient* if starting from that means it will recur infinitely often with probability $0$.

Denoting by $P_i$ the probability that after starting from state $i$ the Markov process will later return to state $i$ *at least once*, it can be shown state $i$ is *recurrent* if $P_i = 1$ and *transient* if $P_i < 1$.

It follows that every state is either recurrent or transient (never both).  In a **finite** Markov process there will always be **at least one recurrent state**, and it is *possible* for all states to be recurrent (so in some cases there could be *no* transient states).  See also [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340651/is-the-state-space-of-a-transient-irreductible-markov-chain-infinite) about the need for infinitely many states to have all states be transient.

A simple example of a Markov process with at least one transient state is to have an *aborbing state* together with another state, say given by the matrix:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

State $j$ is recurrent iff state $i$ is recurrent if $p_{i,j}^r >0$ and $p_{j,i}^s >0$ for some
$r,s<\infty$.

For finite connected $G$, every state can be reached from every other state i.e., $p_{i,j}^{n_{i,j}}>0$ for some $n_{i,j}<\infty$ for every $i,j$ and one of the states say state $m$ is recurrent. Hence all states are recurrent.

See:
https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.110/lehre/ws13/Stochastik_II/Skript_2B.pdf